# Cherry-pick Jekyll collection output

Tags: jekyll

### Setup:

- I have a Jekyll collection of 800 items
- I've set `output: false` as I don't need individual pages for each one, and want to save time on builds
- I *do*, however, want to be able to `output: true` on select items

### Question

Is there a way to do this? I tried overriding the `output` variable in the selected item's front matter, but that didn't seem to make difference.

I do know about `published: true/false`, but I need for all files to be `published:true` for their data to remain available elsewhere in my site. This question pertains to their *output as pages*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two collections, one with `output: true` (**col1**) and the other with no output (**col2**).

Now if you want to loop over both collections in single pass, you can concatenate them :

```
{% assign all = site.col1 | concat: site.col2 %}
```

And if you have the same datas in both collections, you can sort item like this :

```
{% assign all = site.col1 | concat: site.col2 | sort: 'title' %}
```